# 'Little would he have imagined'

Tags: sentence-construction, conditionals

> When his predecessor Donald Trump's home in Mar-a-Lago, Florida, was raided last August and a trove of thousands of government documents was discovered there, including several hundreds of classified papers, **little would U.S. President Joe Biden have imagined that he would find himself in a similar sticky situation**'

```
                —The Hindu,24Jan 2023
```

I found this paragraph in an article in today's newspaper.

**Little did he know** means 'that he didn't know' so **Little would he have imagined** would mean perhaps 'he wouldn't have imagined'.

My question is how 'would have' is used here when there is no conditional or volitional element, where you wanted to do sth but didn't, in the sentence.
As those are the only conditions of using 'would have' so how it was used???

Comment: 'The rock fell out of the sky and hit the man on the head. He would not have known he was about to die' - does this violate your 'rule'?

Comment: @Michael Harvey But all the sites I checked they only talk about two usages of 'would have'. So I thought that might be the case. But it seems it is not. Thankyou.

Comment: Can you give a detail explanation on what are the possibile situations where we can use?

Comment: Please see [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/will-have-and-would-have)

Comment: The cited example is a bit "odd". There's no good reason to use the conditional there, and I suggest that almost everyone else would just say *little **did** U.S. President Joe Biden **imagine** that...* The cited writer is just getting carried away with his utterly pointless verbosity.

Comment: I just asked google **how many classified documents were found at  Donald Trump's home in Mar-a-Lago**. The results on the first couple of pages include the numbers 3, 11, 38, 100, 300, 350... (and one reference to 700 ***pages***, to big it up to the max). But I didn't find any mention of ***thousands*** as per the cited text here. I suspect our writer just made that up..

Comment: @FumbleFingers The paper is considered as left-leaning in my country. So yeah I kind of expect lil exaggeration while reading.

Comment: RADS - I don't really expect a current *google* query to take much notice of the specific word ***classified*** in my search, but by this time next year it's quite possible that a hybrid "ChatGPT + Wolfram Alpha" engine will be capable of meaningfully including that constraint. That'll make it a *lot* easier to see who's bending the truth most!

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah! I hope too. Btw you said the writer used conditional there. So, it is of the case where 'if- clause' is missing. Can you give examples  of what are the possibile if-clauses which can come with it

Comment: Your cited example is a "pseudo-conditional" usage. Something that Biden *wouldn't have* imagined is really no different to something he *didn't* imagine. The modal auxiliary ***would*** is just there for effect - we *could* say it's a "conditional" *(**If** we could ascertain the truth, **we would find that** Biden didn't imagine something),* but it's not really. It''s just stylistic circumlocution.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the answer!!!

Comment: @RADS - That 'several hundreds of classified papers' marks the origin as unlikely to be US or UK. A Google search suggests that it is an opinion (editorial) piece in _The Hindu_ (India). I am very curious to know why you think that being 'left-leaning' necessarily implies exaggeration.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457) "Today's newspaper" is not a sufficient attribution.

Comment: _The Hindu_ has been praised for its 'championing of reason over emotion, for its dedication to principle even in the face of criticism and popular disapproval'.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I will try to add Sources from next time. Thankyou for the link.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have been reading it for months and I have felt while reading some exaggeration on criticizing government policies and on aggrandising opposition's action. I never meant to generalise that left-leaning necessarily implies exaggeration. What I said was referring to that newspaper in particular. I don't know I can post a Quora link here or not but you will find there common opinion about this newspaper.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  I saw closing proposal on the question so I added the sources...hope it would help in not getting it closed.

Comment: @RADS Thanks for editing in a source cite. Please do this on future posts here. There is no longer a reason to close this for lacking a cite, in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the "*would*" form in "*Little would he have imagiend...*" invites the reader to think of an alternate reality in which he **did** imagine it. This is not, strictly speaking a conditional. Instead it uses teh [subjunctive](https://languagetool.org/insights/post/grammar-subjunctive-mood/) which is used to discuss statements contrary to fact, hypothetical statements, and wishes or requests. It is sometimes uoused with or as part of conditional statements.

In this case it really has not actual meaning beyond "He didn't imagine" but it emphasized the difference between what he might have imagined (but didn't) and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

I read this as follows: *If* you could travel back in time to the start of the Mar-a-Lago scandal and find out what Biden was thinking then, he would not be imagining that something similar might happen to him later.

The choice of *would* emphasizes that the writer is setting up a hypothetical about observing past-Biden's mental state. *Did* suggests that the writer is reporting on what past-Biden was actually thinking (which is presumably hard to know unless he was interviewed at the time).

Compare: "John lived in the 1600s, so he **would** not have had indoor plumbing." The *would* indicates that the speaker is making an inference about the protagonist, rather than reporting on a direct piece of knowledge.